# Average based on a Criteria/ Condition Numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, average

So I want to take the average of all values in column b when column a is a particular and plot it using Matplotlib.

[image]

So in the table above I want to average out the values in B and E for every same value in A and hence create a new element where

A =57 B= Avg of all values of b where A= 57 E= Avg of all values of e where A =57 and so on

And then finally plot the new element

I tried to implement it by taking the values into another Identity matrix but that does not work.

```
for x in list_of_entries:
    Final['A'] = x;
    Final['C'] = 0;
    Final['D'] = 1;
    I = np.logical_and((1), (data_temp['A'].astype(int) == x)) 
    Final['B'] =  np.average(data_temp[I]['B']);
    Final['E'] =  np.average(data_temp[I]['E']);
    np.empty(I);
```

Comment: Is `data_temp` a Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: No just a numpy array

Comment: data_temp= np.genfromtxt(dir_readfile, dtype=float, delimiter='\t', names = names, usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5], skip_header=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NumPy only, you could use `np.unique(..., return_indx=True)` to find the indices which demarcate the chunks with constant `A` value:

```
data_temp.sort(order=['A'])
uniqs, idx = np.unique(data_temp['A'], return_index=True)
idx = np.r_[idx, len(data_temp)]
# >>> idx
# array([  0,  10,  20,  33,  42,  50,  58,  71,  79,  90, 100])
```

Then you can access the chunks of `data_temp` with constant `A` value using

```
data_temp[idx[i], idx[i+1]]
```

for each `i = 0,..., len(idx)-1`.

This is quicker than using

```
for val in uniqs:
    mask = data_temp['A'] == val
    chunk = data_temp.loc[mask]
```

because accessing basic slices is much faster than advanced indexing with boolean selection masks.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2016)

data_temp = np.random.randint(10, size=(6*100)).view(
    [(col, '<i8')for col in list('ABCDEF')])
data_temp.sort(order=['A'])
uniqs, idx = np.unique(data_temp['A'], return_index=True)
idx = np.r_[idx, len(data_temp)]

result = []
for i in range(len(idx)-1):
    val = uniqs[i]
    start, end = idx[i], idx[i+1]
    # Uncomment to see the chunks of `data_temp` with constant A value
    # print(data_temp[start:end])
    mean = {col:data_temp[col][start:end].mean() for col in ['B', 'E']}
    result.append([val, mean['B'], 0, 1, mean['E']])
result = np.array(result)
print(result)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(result[:, 0], result[:, 1])
ax.plot(result[:, 0], result[:, 4])
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you have [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), the whole calculation becomes incredibly simple:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data_temp = pd.read_csv(dir_readfile, delimiter='\t', skiprows=1, names=names, 
    usecols=list(range(6)))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
result = data_temp.groupby('A').agg({'B':'mean', 'E':'mean'})
result.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: By the way thanks for the pandas code. Much simpler then Numpy only.

Comment: Just a quick follow up. Lets say I want to also add another condition where in I want values in B and E which are unique to A and D so A= 57 and D= 0 mean B and mean C. Now I added another column in group by and that seems to work. Wondering how to plot them though like A= 57 D= 0 one plot then on the same graph A = 57 D =1 and so on.

Comment: You might be looking for `result = data_temp.groupby(['A', 'D']).agg({'B':'mean', 'C':'mean'})`, but then again I might not be understanding you properly. If not, please post a new question showing sample input and desired output.

Comment: Yep i will ask another once I do some R&D on my own. Thanks for your help again.